# Can't remotely connect to VirtualBox guest via VRDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, remote-access

At work, I have a desktop computer running Ubuntu 11.04 with VirtualBox installed. I want to run a Red Hat virtual machine (guest) on the work desktop computer (host).

On my laptop at home, I ssh'ed into the desktop to start the VM using

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm centos_54_64
```

Then I tried to access the virtual machine using rdesktop but I keep getting an error!

```
rdesktop -a 16 -N host_ip:3389
Autoselected keyboard map en-us
ERROR: host_ip: unable to connect
```

The virtual machine is graphic-less. There's only a terminal. Here's the relevant information on my virtual machine:

```
NIC 1: MAC: 080027BBCE0F, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'eth0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny
NIC 2: disabled
NIC 3: disabled
NIC 4: disabled
NIC 5: disabled
NIC 6: disabled
NIC 7: disabled
NIC 8: disabled
VRDE:  enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 3389, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you able to connect with SSH?

Comment: I'm no pro but this makes no sense to me: "I tried to access the virtual machine using rdesktop" and "virtual machine is graphic-less" Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it! Woot!

You need to install the extension pack for this to work! I misunderstood the documentation.

The base install of VirtualBox only gives you the VRDE (VirtualBox Remote Desktop Extension) which by itself is just an interface.

The extension pack gives you Oracle's implementation of this interface in the form of VRDP which is backwards compatible with RDP which lets you use rdesktop!

All the acronyms had me confused. Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, nice! I had a similar problem. What was strange to me is that it used to work, so I was really confused. They must have changed that in one of the updates.

Comment: @Marc is there any way of connecting without installing the extensions?

Comment: Yeah you can also connect to your VM using SSH, which is what I do now. If your VM doesn't have a desktop (i.e. it's just a terminal), VRDP will give you no added benefit. I don't remember why I was using it TBH haha...